# How to pass a pointer to array in a function, modify it, and return back properly?

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference

I am attempting to pass a pointer to array in a function and return it back. The problem is that after correct initializing the function returns a NULL-pointer. Can anyone tell me, what is the issue with my logic?

Here is my  function, where array is declared:

```
void main()
{
     int errCode;
     float *pol1, *pol2;
     pol1 = pol2 = NULL;
     errCode = inputPol("A", pol1);
     if (errCode != 0)
     { 
         return;
     }

     // using pol1 array

     c = getchar();
}
```

And here is the function with initialization:

```
int inputPol(char* c, float *pol)
{
    pol= (float *) calloc(13, sizeof( float ) );
    while( TRUE )
    {
         // While smth happens
         pol[i] = 42;
         i++;
    };
}
```

Comment: You need to turn up your compiler warning level (or pay attention to your warnings) so you don't write non-void functions without `return` statements.  :-/

Comment: Is the code that you are posting the complete code you are running?  I see and infinite loop in the inputPol function and you are not returning the error code.

Comment: p.s. you don't need to cast result of `calloc` in C

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the address of pol1, so main knows where the allocated memory is:

```
void main()
{
    int errCode;
    float *pol1, *pol2;
    pol1 = pol2 = NULL;
    errCode = inputPol("A", &pol1);
    if (errCode != 0)
    { 
         return;
    }

    // using pol1 array

    c = getchar();
}

int inputPol(char* c, float **pol)
{
    *pol= (float *) calloc(13, sizeof( float ) );
    while( TRUE )
    {
         // While smth happens
         (*pol)[i] = 42;
         i++;
    };
}
```